# Technical term for bit packing

Tags: bit-manipulation, bit

By bit packing I mean since `int` is of 4 bytes, and if we store `1` inside the `int`, remaining bits will be wasted.
So I'll be packing the next type e.g `short`'s value `2`, in the `int` variable (by right left shifts).

What is this technique called?

Comment: @Oded Yeah, but "packing" on its own doesn't hint out anything.

Comment: We have a fixed size of data that can be passed through sockets at one go @Stijn

Comment: Searching google for the term 'bit packing' suggests this is the technical term.

Comment: @Stijn I think I'll have to stick with this word only, btw did my OP make any sense to you?

Comment: @AnishaKaul It makes sense now, I just hadn't heard of something like this before and didn't know of its practical applications. I've read it's used in compression.

Comment: Thanks @Stijn  BTW, data compression won't be an appropriate term for this, IMO. Though definitely it is a form of compression. :) Am I right?

Comment: Isn't this a form of variable length encoding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said it yourself; *Bit Packing*.

If you are packing *individual bits*, the result would be a *Bitfield*. But in this case of two `short`s in the space of an `integer`, it could also be just *byte packing*.

But all-in all it is *Packing*.